# Symfony3 Doctrine working with timezones

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, doctrine-orm, symfony

I just migrated a Symfony2.4 project to Symfony3.0 and I am facing a wierd situation.

The project's default timezone is UTC, everything is stored as UTC timestamps in the MYSQL database.

I retrieve an entry with a datetime field named 'checkOut', pass it to the twig template:

```
<p>{{ dump(entity.checkOut) }}</p>
<p>{{ dump(entity.checkOut.getTimestamp()) }}</p>
```

And I get:

```
DateTime {#585 ▼
  +"date": "2016-09-17 10:46:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
1474109160
```

which is correct.

But my app should support users from different timezones. So I store a users preferred timezone and use an event listener to set it

```
date_default_timezone_set($this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getTimezone());
```

After that the same entry displays:

```
DateTime {#585 ▼
  +"date": "2016-09-17 10:46:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Asia/Jakarta"
}
1474083960
```

This is clearly wrong as the timestamp is now different. I would expect this:

```
DateTime {#585 ▼
  +"date": "2016-09-17 17:46:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Asia/Jakarta"
}
1474109160
```

This used to work fine in sf2.4. Can Anyone explain what the problem is and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are changing the default timezone of your server rather than changing the timezone of the DateTime instance in question. One of my pet hates!

I am not familiar with twig, but doing something like this would give you the expected result:-

```
<p>{{ dump(entity.checkOut) }}</p>
<p>{{ dump(entity.checkOut.setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone("Asia/Jakarta"))) }}</p>
<p>{{ dump(entity.checkOut.getTimestamp()) }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is indeed a solution but would require me to update every template on the website. Also there are cases where for example I have to get all records of a specific month and in those cases I should also take into account the user's timezone. Changing the default timezone is very convenient because everything is calculated with the user's timezone.

Comment: Convenient yes, but still wrong as you are experiencing.